# Asocia fecha y valor

Tags: php, api

Estoy trabajando con al API de [weatherstack](https://weatherstack.com/documentation) en donde tengo que obtener de la fecha histórica, el día y la lluvia acumulada para poder crear una grafica.

Tengo este error en donde me dice que `date` no esta definida; `Warning: Undefined array key "date" in`

Este es el código

```
public function precipitaciones($fechasInicio, $fechaFin, $latitud, $longitud){

    # Rango de dias de ventana
    $ventanaInicio = strtotime('-1 year', strtotime($fechaInicio));
    $ventanaInicio = date('Y-m-d', $ventanaInicio);
    $ventanaFin    = strtotime('-1 year', strtotime($fechaFin));
    $ventanaFin    = date('Y-m-d', $ventanaFin);

    $rango = $this->completadorFechas($ventanaInicio, $ventanaFin);

    # API
    $key = "";
    $api = "http://api.weatherstack.com/historical?access_key=".$key."&query=".$latitud.",".$longitud."&historical_date=".$rango."&hourly=1";

    $json       = file_get_contents($api);
    $datos      = json_decode($json, true);
    $contedor   = 0;
    $fechas     = array();
    $milimetros = array();

    foreach($datos["historical"] as $row){
        $hora = $row['hourly'];

        $array = array();

        foreach($hora as $v){
            $array = array($fechas => $v['date'], $milimetros => $v['precip']);
        }

        $res = $array;
    }


    return $res;

}
```

Comment: Mirando la API para [Historical Weather](https://weatherstack.com/documentation#historical_weather) se puede ver que los registros en `hourly` no tienen `date`, sino `time`. El dato `date` estaría en `$row`

Comment: Si si... `date` esta dentro de `hourly`, pero ya pude resolverlo... gracias!

Comment: Considera publicar la solución o eliminar la pregunta.